# Find 'friend of a friend' relations in one Select (SUBSELECT and/or JOIN)

Tags: mysql

I have a "relationship" matrix like:

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| name    | Albert     | Bob        | Charles    | Dale       | Ethan      |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Albert  |            |    0       |    1       |    1       |   -1       |
| Bob     |            |            |    1       |   -1       |    1       |
| Charles |            |            |            |    0       |    1       |
| Dale    |            |            |            |            |    0       |
| Ethan   |            |            |            |            |            |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
 0 means they don't know each other
 1 means they like each other
-1 means they don't like each other
```

Now, I want to input two names and get the number of mutual known people and 'speculate' on their relationship by adding up the 'likes' (preferable in one single SELECT).

For example take the pair of Charles and Dale:

> Charles knows Albert and Bob, who also know Dale.
>  The relationship
>   between Charles and Dale would probably be friendly since Charles
>   likes Albert (+1) who likes Dale (+1) and Charles likes Bob (+1)
>   though Bob does not like Dale (-1).
>
> So, the output would be 2 mutual known people and a 'speculation' of +3.

I can't get my head around a functional subselect query, plus the fact that the matrix is only half-filled seems to make it more complicated (sometimes a name is the first index, sometimes it is the second).

Could someone help me formulate a useful query, please?

Comment: Please make some attempt to solve the problem yourself first. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: I am sorry. But this is not for work at all, just a hobby. I started with php+mysql stuff few days ago and I have serious trouble coming up with conditions for my queries to find the things I am looking for. Also, I know I could probably compare output tables in php, but that seems not trivial as well.

Comment: We're not here to do your hobby for you, either. You'll learn best by trying to do it yourself. Or search for other questions like yours (take a look at some of the **Related** questions).

Comment: I will say first modify your Table structure with fixed number of columns. Since if any person added to table then  there will be a separate column for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment above you should modfify your table structure to something more sensible.
So we assume tables like:

**Person** - Columns: (PersonId, Name)

**PersonRelationships** - Columns: (Person1Id, Person2Id, Relationship)

Then a query might look like:

```
DECLARE @Person1Id INT;
DECLARE @Person2Id INT;
SET @Person1Id = 1;
SET @Person2Id = 2;

SELECT SUM(r1.Relationship + r2.Relationship)
(
    SELECT 
      Person2Id AS CommonRelatedPersonId, Relationship
    FROM PersonRelationships
    WHERE Person1Id = @Person1Id
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      Person1Id AS CommonRelatedPersonId, Relationship
    FROM PersonRelationships
    WHERE Person2Id = @Person1Id
) r1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
      Person2Id AS CommonRelatedPersonId, Relationship
    FROM PersonRelationships
    WHERE Person1Id = @Person2Id
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      Person1Id AS CommonRelatedPersonId, Relationship
    FROM PersonRelationships
    WHERE Person2Id = @Person2Id
) r2 ON r1.CommonRelatedPersonId = r2.CommonRelatedPersonId;
```

Please excuse any syntax errors - I'm more used to MS SQL Server syntax.
Still you should be able to see the concept - you need a relationship table, linking people, and you need to assume the link could be in either direction (hence the unions above)

Join 2 unioned (A-> B + B -> A) copies together on the common related person and sum the total and you're there.